# Identify and close inactive thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, multithreading

In my app (speed traps & hazards) I'm using a several kinds of threads: `NSOperation`, `dispatch_async`, `performSelectorInBackground`, `performSelectorOnMainThread` and so on.

I want to do 2 things;

1. Identify the tread by his name in xcode `Debug Navigator`.
2. Close dead/inactive threads.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Threads should stop and disappear when they have finished their task, at least that is true for NSOperation and dispatch_async. So why do you want to achieve this?

Comment: If they are finished then how they are still there? Shouldn't they has to gone and removed as the threads numbered 11-17 in my screenshot? If they're still there presumably they still consuming memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dispatch_queue_create to create thread with name. 
Then you will be able to see thread and pause them in Xcode. 
Or you can store in temporary variable and stop when you want in your app.

[image]

Comment: What about 'NSOperation' & 'performSelector', is there any change to identify?

Comment: @IdanMoshe "performSelector" - performing in the same thread. NSOperation usually has name "Thread #_NUM, Queue : NSOperationQueue 0x000000_address"